# формирования отчетов php

Tags: php, javascript, css, mysql, html5

Есть поисковик по базе данных в процессе выполнения поиска происходит выдача результата
[image: пример вывода поиска]
после чего нужно создать кнопку например "создать отчет"  в результате создать файл pdf, xml, doc и т.д. в зависимости от выбора пользователя.

С помощь чего можно сделать формирования отчетов новичку,  формирование и выгрузки печатных форм отчетов на php c базы mysql?

Есть ли специальные библиотеки или простые примеры в решении данного вопроса?

Comment: Проще всего? Ну это очевидно - нанять специалиста.

Comment: Пожалуйста утоните вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить данные из базы и использовать формат PDF

http://php.net/manual/ru/pdf.examples-basic.php

Печать точно не поедет за поля.
Можно так же использовать CSV формат.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fputcsv.php